# need to show light box pop up on an ADD Gallery slide show

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have  a `PHP` project, and I am using ADD Gallery image slide show. Here on the main image, (large image) when click on that large image  I need to show that in a pop up like Light box.
But I don't know how. Is it work both the add gallery and Light box?

Comment: Have you searched anything? Just google lightbox and you will find that **lightbox ain't using JAVASCRIPT**. It is using JQuery for its animation.

Comment: Here is your reference http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/

Answer (score 0):

You can't achieve it by just `PHP, HTML and JAVASCRIPT`. You need `Modal Dialog boxes`. This will need a good skill in not only `HTML & CSS` but also `JQuery`. Here are 14 jQuery Modal Pop ups you might want to use.

http://www.jquery4u.com/windows/14-jquery-modal-dialog-boxes/

Customize them as per your requirements.